# How can I simplify this code with a for loop to update many controls?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, textbox

I have done the following code and works well. I am wondering how I can do a for loop to clean this code from 38 lines into 2 lines.

```
        s0s.Text = seg[0].start.ToString("X8");
        s0e.Text = seg[0].end.ToString("X8");
        s1s.Text = seg[1].start.ToString("X8");
        s1e.Text = seg[1].end.ToString("X8");
        // .. many more ..
        s19s.Text = seg[19].start.ToString("X8");
        s19e.Text = seg[19].end.ToString("X8");
```

I can obviously do the `seg[i]` substitution, but how do i do it with the text boxes?

Comment: Can you clarify what type `seg` is?

Comment: seg is an array where i store segment information. as defined here.

        byte[] bin;
        segment[] seg;

Comment: It is not clear what a `segment` object is. Can you show its structure? I am just confused on the `.start` and `.end` properties, which do not exist in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use the [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netcore-3.1) property and call [`OfType<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) to get all the instances of `TextBoxes` in your `Form` *instance*

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Then convert the results to a `Dictionary` based on the control `Name`

```
// this could potentially be done in the constructor
var dict = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToDictionary(x => x.Name);

for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    dict[$"s{i}s"].Text = $"{seg[i].Start:X8}";
    dict[$"s{i}e"].Text = $"{seg[i].End:X8}";
}
```

<sub>***Note** : This code is untested and only a guide to a possible solution*</sub>

Comment: Would the code not crash if one of keys in the `dict` does NOT match one of the strings “sXs” or “sXe”? The code is grabbing all the text boxes. Also, what if there are less than 19 text  boxes? I would think you have to at least group those text boxes with some container.

Comment: @JohnG yeah the assumption is that the TextBoxes exist. You are right that it will grab all the text boxes, and it would likely be better if they were parented to some control (on  more complex form).

Comment: I agree, and I am still not sure WHAT `seg` is? I am not sure what `.start` or `.end` mean. `seg`  is not a string array or list.

Comment: seg is just short for segment and its a name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to do it this way.  First create two lists of your controls, the starts and the ends:

```
var starts = new List<TextBox>
{
    s0s,
    s1s,
    //...
    s19s
};
var ends = new List<TextBox>
{
    s0e,
    s1e,
    //...
    s19e
};
```

Then loop over each list:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var start in starts)
{
    start.Text = seg[i].start.ToString("X8");
    ++i;
}
i = 0;
foreach (var end in ends)
{
    start.Text = seg[i].end.ToString("X8");
    ++i;
}
```

Your indexes and control numbers would need to line up perfectly though.

***Note:** Like TheGeneral's code, this is untested (neither of us wants to create a form with 38 text boxes with specific names)*

Comment: If i have to do this then its not much different than what i have now. I may have some more letters into the code but that is it. I would still be having to define it one by one. I was looking for a way that could add the variable to middle letter of the name so i can reference it with a loop.

Comment: @highlander: the difference is that, in my case, you are first declaring which objects you are going to be operating on, then describing the operation you will be doing. If your specs change, and you need to do something different to those controls, all you need to do is change one or both of those short loops. In you original code, you'd need to carefully make changes to 38 lines of dense code. You should always be thinking about *maintainability* when you write code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the textboxes names I would suggest alternative approach to use control designed to display collection of things - DataGridView would be one of the options.

With data binding you can achieve little bit more maintainable code

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Start { get; set; }

    public int End { get; set; }
}
```

In the form create a datagridview with two bounded columns, you can do this in winforms designer without manually writing the code below.

```
// constructor
public MyForm()
{
    var startColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    startColumn.DataPropertyName = "Start"; // Name of the property in MyItem class
    startColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "X8";

    var endColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    endColumn.DataPropertyName = "End"; // Name of the property in MyItem class
    endColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "X8";

    myDataGridView.Columns.AddRange(startColumn, endColumn);
    myDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false; 
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = new List<MyItem>
    {
        new MyItem { Start = 10, End = 20 },
        new MyItem { Start = 11, End = 19 },
        new MyItem { Start = 12, End = 18 }
    };

    myDataGridView.DataSource = items;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

firstly when you create they variables insert them all to an array. then run a loop as following:

```
for (int i; int < 19(your list); i++)
{
    your list[i].Text = seg[i].start.ToString("X8");
    your list[i].Text = seg[i].end.ToString("X8");
}
```

Comment: Yes but what about the s 0 s.text. The i must match the number between s... for example

         s1s.Text = seg[1].start.ToString("X8"); etc etc etc.